# Woocommerce replacing featured product image on product archive with video

Tags: css, image, woocommerce, elementor

Since I didn't find any plugin which helps with my issue (at least in elementor) I've tried to write some custom code to achieve following.
I want to replace the featured image on the shop page (product archive) with a video(trailer snipped). Currently I'm trying to use this in combination with an ACF text area field I've created, with the custom iframe code in it, which get's pulled from each specific product.

This is the code I've wrote

```
function replace_featured_image_with_acf_video_on_mouseover() {
    // Get the product ID
    $product_id = get_the_ID();

    // Get the raw ACF code from the 'featuredvideo' field
    $raw_code = get_field('featuredvideo', $product_id);

    // Output the container for the video
    echo '<div class="custom-featured-video-container">';
    echo '<div class="custom-featured-video" data-raw-code="' . esc_attr($raw_code) . '"></div>';
    echo '</div>';

    // Output the default featured image as a fallback
    woocommerce_template_single_featured_image();
}

remove_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'replace_featured_image_with_acf_video_on_mouseover', 20);
```

Somehow it's not working, the code is from snippets I've combinded which I think should in general work.

Another thing I wanted to achieve is that the format of each product in the product archive is the same as the videos 3:1

I've tried using this code

```
function replace_featured_image_with_acf_video_on_mouseover() {
    // Get the product ID
    $product_id = get_the_ID();

    // Get the raw ACF code from the 'featuredvideo' field
    $raw_code = get_field('featuredvideo', $product_id);

    // Output the container for the video
    echo '<div class="custom-featured-video-container">';
    echo '<div class="custom-featured-video" data-raw-code="' . esc_attr($raw_code) . '"></div>';
    echo '</div>';

    // Output the default featured image as a fallback
    woocommerce_template_single_featured_image();
}

remove_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'replace_featured_image_with_acf_video_on_mouseover', 20);
```

to replace the featured product image in the product archive with a video.